# Can I disable editing on my questions?

Tags: support, questions, edits

I've had questions that I've asked be edited into an entirely different question and thus receive irrelevant answers. Is there any way to prevent others from editing my questions without permission?

Comment: No, such thing would be against the very spirit of Stack Exchange, which is a network of community driven/moderated sites. You're free to rollback edits if you think they are unjustified and in case of edit war, a moderator would step in and decide what to do.

Comment: Not really, once posted, your post belongs and will be edited by the community.

Comment: While disabling editing is highly undesirable, this question is not a feature request suggesting editing be disabled. It is a support question regarding if it is possible or not. I don't think over zealously downvoting it serves any purpose.

Comment: @ShadowWizardLoveZelda I completely disagree. Editing someone else's words, without permission, is the same as putting words in their mouths. That should be "against the very spirit of Stack Exchange, which is a network of community driven/moderated sites.". Yes there is a time a phrase or some punctuation is needed for clarity, but it should be a Suggestion not an "I'm gonna do it and let so many other people see it before you realize, I made you say something, that you didn't say, without you even knowing about it." Editing someone's Words should be a suggestion first and wait for approval.

Comment: @Mouthpear it's fine to disagree, but I stand behind what I say, and glad to see others here, including those who actually decide, agree with it as well, and that is the current policy. If it will change, e.g. users won't be able to edit anymore, I'll just leave, which is fine.

Comment: @ShadowWizardLoveZelda So you will leave because you would have the ability to change, alter, rewrite what a person says and even add things that they didn't say? WOW. Are these the ONLY forums (SE and the network) you are on? There are so MANY more sites that don't operate that way. Do you not engage because you can't edit? Do you not watch youtube either, since you can't alter their videos? In any case I find that altering someone else's speech is, without permission, is a horrible thing. Tyrants do that and it doesn't end well.

Comment: @Mouthpear I would leave because the result will be pile of low quality content that nobody can improve anymore.

Answer (score 21):

The answer is no. Anyone with 2k (on a graduated site) reputation can edit any other question or answer, aside from moderator locked posts (and those can't be answered either, so you don't want that).

The reason for that being that Stack Exchange is about content quality, and we believe that being able to edit any post is a great tool to keep question quality high (fix tpyos, mistakes on grammar, etc).

If someone edited your question and changed too much of the context, you can roll it back.

[image: Example]

Also see: [Why can people edit my posts? How does editing work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/editing)

Answer (score 20):

No, community editing is part of the Stack Exchange model.  See [why can people edit my posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/editing).

If an edit puts words in your mouth or is otherwise not acceptable to you, you can roll it back.  Understand that the community is trying to help and probably edited because the original version of the question wasn't workable on the site where you asked it.  So rolling back edits could lead to the question being put on hold until you yourself edit it to address whatever the problem is.

Once a question has answers, it's generally considered inappropriate to edit a question in a way that invalidates any of the answers.

Check the edit summary and comments for explanations of the edits that people are making.  If you don't understand the problem, use meta or the site's chat room to ask for help.  The community wants to help you ask a good question that fits on the site so you can get good answers.  If an editor seems to have not understood what you meant, talk to each other to sort it out.

Comment: Worth noting that we can ask clarifications to the editors using `@editorName` in a comment.